# SSRS report external image source

Tags: reporting-services, http-headers, http-streaming

I am trying to create a solution to show dynamic images in SSRS reports. I have .NET process that generates Base64 strings that after decoding returned to the client. Here is C# code:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
MemoryStream exportStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
exportStream.Position = 0;
return Ok(exportStream);
```

where image is the Base64 string.
It works fine when a client is a Browser. But in the report it shows Red X when I am running it in the report builder. Published report shows nothing at all. Seems like the report doesn't fully understand the return format or something else. Please share any idea.

Thanks

Image properties:
[image]

Comment: Are you using the image field directly in the report or doing any conversions? What about the MIME type? Can you show the image properties in SSRS

Comment: See my updated question.